# как закрепить заголовки таблицы при скролинге страницы в jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasperreports, jasperstudio

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. При скролинге часть заголовков обрезается. Никак не могу решить проблему.[image: заголовки таблицы].[image: Пример обрезки]

на американском форуме задавал аналогичный вопрос. Посоветовали выделить заголовки таблицы нажать правую кнопку мыши и идти по пути - Select XLS Tags-->Freeze . Но данное решение не помогло. Заголовок таблицы вроде как и замораживается, но при скролинге все равно часть наименований обрезает как на скриншоте. https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1188021/how-fix-table-column-headers-report

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Как пробовали решать, куда смотрели? Можете предоставить больше информации

Comment: на американском форуме задавал аналогичный вопрос. Посоветовали выделить заголовки таблицы нажать правую кнопку мыши и идти по пути - Select XLS Tags-->Freeze . Но данное решение не помогло. Заголовок таблицы вроде как и замораживается, но при скролинге все равно часть наименований обрезает как на скриншоте.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку)